# How do I copy local files to remote server where remote server needs root access with scp?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, permissions, ssh

I am connecting to a server (`ssh user@server`) where I need to do the following to act as the `root` user:

```
dzdo su -
```

Without `su -` I can't copy any file on this server and have only read-only access.

Now, I want to copy a folder from my local to this remote server. This is what I tried when in the local `bash` terminal and as expected it gives me a *Permission denied* error (as follows):

Any idea what I should do here?

**Copy from local directory to the remote server:**

```
(base) Username@Local_Computer lsp % scp -r /Users/Username/Downloads/lsp  username@server:/srv/path/directory
```

**Error I get:**

```
scp: /srv/path/directory: Permission denied`
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the command `chmod` and `chown` after you do `dzdo su -` on the remote server? If so, you can change the ownership or permissions of the remote directory into which you are trying to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following (on the local machine):

```
% cd /Users/Username/Downloads/
% tar -cvf - lsp | ssh username@server 'dzdo tar -C /srv/path/directory -xvf -'
```

or

```
% cd /Users/Username/Downloads/
% tar -cvf - lsp | ssh username@server 'dzdo sudo su - -c "tar -C /srv/path/directory -xvf -"'
```

This command sequence will `tar` the local file(s) and send the `tar` output to *stdout*. The command sequence given in the second parameter of `ssh` will run a second `tar` command on the remote server with `dzdo` privileges that will extract the file(s) coming from *stdin* to the  directory specified in the `-C` parameter of `tar` command there.

Please note that the `tar` command(s) will copy the ownership and file permission information from the local system to the remote server also. For example, if the user id and group id of the file owner on the local system is 1000 and 1000 and the file permissions are `-rw-r--r--`,  the same user, group ids, and file permissions will be used on the remote server. However, **that user and group id may belong to *another* user or group on the remote server**. There are options in `tar` that will allow to change this. See the options: `--group=`, `--owner=`, `--no-same-owner`, `--no-same-permissions`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking out the time to reply. I executed it and get this error: > Sorry, user `username` is not allowed to execute '/bin/tar -xvf -' as root on `server`.

Comment: Can you replace the `ssh ...` command with `ssh username@server 'dzdo sudo su - -c "tar -C /srv/path/directory -xvf -"'` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this second one also gave the error: >>> Sorry, user `username` is not allowed to execute '/bin/sudo su - -c tar -C `/srv/path/directory` -xvf -' as root on `server`

Comment: Are you able to execute a command like `tar`, `chown`, `chmod` etc. as root after you run the command `dzdo su -`?